# Finding multiple files and copying them to another location in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, file, search, copying

I have been tasked with updating some items on our website with new pictures. I have a list of around 2000 SKU. They all follow the same format of `XX01234`. There will be images named `XX01234.tif`. However, some of the images may be named `XX01234_outdoors.tif`. 
I need to copy all .tif files with `XX01234` in the file name to another folder. 
With around 2000 SKU's I'm having trouble finding a way to do these all at once. I've tried some programs and using regex commands but unfortunately, this is quite a bit different from anything I do normally.

Comment: Please update your question with what you have tried so far and what specifically was failing :) I think Robocopy would be the best option if available.

Comment: I have tried `dir | where name -match "XX01234"` just to find files but failed. I have also used a program called grepWin and tried the regex command `^`. I'm sorry if my explanation isn't particularly clear, I've been tasked with this because I'm one of the "computer guys" when in reality I'm not!

Comment: Please, as @I.TDelinquent says, update your question with the relative button, don't add your attemps in the comments

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path <Source_Path> -Filter "XX01234*.tif" -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination <Destination_Path>
```

This should work for you, just replace `<Source_Path>` and `<Destination_Path>` with the actual paths